# Get the value of table data from the same row

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to explain my question the best I can, so sorry if it's a bit confusing.

I have in my HTML Table, with table row, and table data, each row is filled with data from data base, and the table is automatically generated.
Example is below.

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Place ID</th>
                    <th>Map Name</th>
                    <th>Place Name</th>
                    <th>Price 1</th>
                    <th>Price 2</th>
                    <th>Price 3</th>
                    <th>Price 4</th>
                    @if (Auth::user()->role == "admin")
                      <th>Action</th>
                      <th>Booking</th>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <div id="preloader"></div>
            <tbody id="hidden_table_processing">
              @foreach ($places as $place)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $place->place_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->map_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->place_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->price1 }} €</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->price2 }} €</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->price3 }} €</td>
                    <td>{{ $place->price4 }} €</td>
```

For booking table head, its filled with a quick booking button, that is supposed to get the Place ID of the data from the same raw, and shows it inside a popup, bellow is the code that creates the popup and fills the data.

```
<td>{{-- status print --}}

                      @if ($place->status==0)
                      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Quick Book</a>

                      <!-- Modal -->
                      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                          <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                          <form method=POST action="{{ route('admin.place.quickbooking') }}">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Quick Book</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              @csrf
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="usr">ID:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $place->place_id }}" id="qBookingID" name="qID" readonly>
                                <label for="usr">Full Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" id="qBookingFullName" name="qFullName">
                                <label for="usr">Number of Guests:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qBookingNumberOfGuests" name="qNumberOfGuests">
                                <label for="usr">Number of Babies:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qBookingNumberOfBabies" name="qNumberOfBabies">
                                <label for="usr">Check In:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ session()->get('startingRange') }}" id="qBookingStartDate" name="qStartDate" readonly>
                                <label for="usr">Check Out:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ session()->get('endingRange') }}" id="qBookingEndDate" name="qEndDate" readonly><br>
                                <label for="usr">Map Name: {{  $place->map_name }}</label><br>
                                <label for="usr" id="qBookingCreatorName" name="qCreatorName">Booked By: {{  Auth::user()->name }}</label>
                              </div>
                              {{-- <a href="{{ route('admin.place.quickbooking', $place->place_id,) }}">Book</a> --}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;" >Close</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="color: green; border: 1px solid green;" type="submit">Book</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       
                      @endif

                      @if ($place->status==-1)
                        <p>Disabled</p>
                      @endif
                      @if ($place->status==2)
                        <p style="color:red;">Busy</p>
                      @endif
                    </td>
```

My problem is that the auto filled ID is only being filled by the First Data, as no matter which row I click on, the ID stays the same "the first ID from the table"

Any idea what might be causing this, or am I missing something very obvious?
THank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your case the better choice is pass the object place to a function using javascript, every time that you give click the modal appears with the data
that you want to edit or show.

```
<a href="" id="editModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#Mymodal' data-id="{{ $item->id }}">Edit</a>
    @push('script')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('body').on('click', '#editModal', function (event) {
        
            event.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data('id');
            console.log(id)
            let name = {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            let startdate = {{ session()->get('startingRange') }}
            let enddate = {{ session()->get('endingRange') }}
            let bookname = 'Booked By:' + name
            $.get('place/' + id + '/edit', function (data) {
                 $("#qBookingID").val(data.data.place_id);
                 $(#qBookingFullName").val(name);
                 $("#qBookingStartDate").val(startdate);
                 $("#qBookingEndDate").val(enddate);
                 $("#qBookingCreatorName").val(bookname);
                 $('#Mymodal').modal('show');
    
             })
        });
        
        });
  </script>
@endpush
```